# Hide ^C pressing ctrl-c in C

Tags: c, shell, exit

I'm creating my own shell and I would like to disable ^C when any user on any Linux distributation press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.

I don't need to handle the signal SIGINT, I already did it for don't stop the program on <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>. I just want to know how to hide these **two characters ^C**.

Is there any function to call or env variables to set at the start of my program?

EDIT

```
  int a = fork();
  if (!a) {
    char *cmd[] = {"/bin/stty", 0 };
    char *cmd_args[] = {" ", "-echoctl", 0};
    execve(cmd[0], cmd_args, env);
  }
```

Tried this. It removes my ^C on ctrl-c but it still displays a square character, like if the character can't be displayed. It seems to be EOT (003 ascii)

Comment: You need to disable the echo on terminal (but it also means that you need to handle the echo from input yourself).

Comment: How, im not sure to understand

Comment: I think I can with execv and stty -echoctl

Comment: @Olaf yes there is a way.

Comment: execve("stty", cmd_args, env); with cmd_args (-echoctl) does not work, any idea?

Comment: Use `execvp()` instead of `execve()` and don't provide the environment.  Or see if you've got `execvpe()` available if you're sure you need a special environment and not just the inherited environment.  Note that if `echoctl` was set before you started, it would be courteous to reset it when your program exits under control (if it exits out of control, there's nothing you can do, of course — it's out of control).  Note that the `cmd_args` array needs to be like `char *cmd_args[] = { "stty", "-echoctl", 0 };`.

Comment: I edited my code, and it still displays a char ! help :D

Comment: @JohnKugelman: After adding some code, it seems so. Before that it looked more like a terminal  configuration question.

Comment: In your sigint handler function add `print("\b \b" * 2, end="", flush=True)`.

Comment: @nico tf are you talking about?

Comment: I'll explain it in a full example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to delete ^C characters.
In the function that processes the SIGINT signal, print the characters that move the cursor twice to the left, then delete all the characters on the right up to the end of the line.

The example below works on macOS and Raspberry Pi OS.

On Windows this trick is not needed as pressing ctrl+c is silent.

```c
/**
    remove_ctrl_c.c
    gcc remove_ctrl_c.c -o remove_ctrl_c && ./remove_ctrl_c

    Remove the characters ^C with ANSI escape codes.
    (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)

    \b     : Move cursor one character on the left.
    \b     : Idem
    \033[K : Delete all the characters on the right of
             the cursor until the end of the line.
             You can also use two spaces if you prefer,
             but they will be present in the output although
             they are not visible.
    \n     : Add a new line. This is optional,
             but if you remove it and some characters
             are printed on the last line, the terminal
             will add an extra % character to indicate
             that the new line character was absent.

    Note that, as the printf command is buffered,
    we need to use the fflush command before the end
    of the program to force stdout to be updated.
*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>

volatile sig_atomic_t KEYBOARD_INTERRUPT = 0;

void handleSignal(int signal)
{
    KEYBOARD_INTERRUPT = 1;
}

int main()
{
    signal(SIGINT, handleSignal);
    printf("Remove ^C on exit!");
    fflush(stdout);
    while (!KEYBOARD_INTERRUPT)
    {
    }
    printf("\b\b\033[K\n");
    fflush(stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A *signal handler* that calls both `printf()`, `fflush()`, and `exit()`?!?!?!  None of which are async-signal-safe?

Comment: @AndrewHenle, thank you for your comment. I have modified the example accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

The `^C` comes from the echo on the terminal driver in Linux

Here's an example program in C. It first disables saves the current settings, and registers an `atexit` handler to restore settings when the program exits, then disables echo on the terminal of standard input. Then it enters an infinite while loop. When you now type anything on the terminal, *nothing* is displayed, not even that `^C`.

The trick that shells use is that they *completely replace* the input handling on the terminal, switching off the canonical input handling, and reading standard input one character at a time, and handling the echoing on their own - something that requires far more code than is possible in a Stack Overflow answer.

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct termios saved;

void restore(void) {
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSANOW, &saved);
}


int main() {
    struct termios attributes;

    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &saved);
    atexit(restore);

    tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &attributes);
    attributes.c_lflag &= ~ ECHO;
    tcsetattr(STDIN_FILENO, TCSAFLUSH, &attributes);

    printf("Entering the loop\n");
    while(1) {};
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for this but it's a school project, and I can't use some of the functions u're currently using.. Do u think stty could work with a execv

Comment: ... can't use some functions that I am using?! That's the strangest thing I've ever heard! Then what school project this is? Yes stty would work... and stty will call this same function

Comment: I know it's stupid.. But we have every functions forbidden unless they specify someones are authorized. I have a problem with stty, it displays a square, like unwritable character

Comment: If you can only use certain functions, please help us out by listing all of them in your original question.

Answer (score 3):

Running `stty -echoctl` should hide it. See `man stty` for more details.

Comment: Am I supposed to execute it during the Runtime?

Comment: execve("stty", args, env); does not work. Bad answer

Comment: "Does not work" is not a useful thing to say. What happened when you tried? Also, note that execve doesn't search your path, so you need to either fully qualify it or use a wrapper like execvp.

Comment: Should I fork() before do it ? Even with /bin/stty it does not work

Comment: Yes, since the exec family of functions replace the current process rather than creating a new one.

Comment: @Romain-p  you have to use the full path with execve "/bin/stty"!